# Is There Any Way To Avoid Camera Passing Through the GLtf Objects That loaded Inside Our Scene In ThreeJs

Tags: javascript, three.js, model, perspectivecamera, 3d-model

hey there I am working with Threejs and I want to develop an online virtual tour. So I loaded some 3d objects as Booths and a camera with a PointerlockControl and everything works fine but the problem is that the camera will pass through the objects and I think that is not good.is there any way to avoid this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is that the camera is sometimes inside an object and you can see this object from inside (which doesn't look good)?
If so, there are two basic solutions:

1. You can create an objects collision system to detect a camera <=> object collision.
2. A much simpler solution: just set your objects' material like this: `Material.side = THREE.FrontSide`, so the camera will be still able to go inside an object, but this object will be not visible from inside (if that's your problem).

Comment: thanks for your help but it seems that three.js doesn't support collision.js now.

Comment: Yes. That's why I prefer the first approach. It's much easier.